# posting data that is not an input field or a form, looking for a way to submit calculated data

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a web application that used textareas and buttons to gather data that is processed (calculations, filtering and concatenation into a string) into an array.  The buttons and textareas are part of a form.  This array can grow up to several hundred entries.  This data is also displayed to the screen by setting innerhtml to a div, this data is highlighted at key points using  with italic and color.  I was using some Javascript to make a mailto link and write this to a div so that the user could email the data.  The problem is that this mailto will only work if a mail client is set up on the machine, it will not work for a webmail system.

I have made a textarea in the form and using some javascript onsubmit() I write the array to this text area after joining the array together with \n , submit then posts the form to a PHP script on the server that then emails the data.

The text area is deliberately small as it has no use other than acting as a go between and I do not want it to take up space and be a distractionon an already cluttered screen.

Reading around it appears that should I have in an attempt to not pollute my screen display:none for this go between textarea that some browsers will not let this non displayed textarea be posted to the PHP script as part of the form.

Have I any other way of sending this array data to a PHP script?

I could make the textarea very small, have no border, background and text color the same white and tuck it away, make it read only but that seems very clunky.

I would appreciate suggestions.  Many thanks.

Comment: Ajax comes to mind - with a serialize

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOMDocument and get the relevant form elements, thus obtaining their values using node->nodeValue?

Comment: Thank you RamRaider, I have to be honest, unfortunately I have no idea about what you are suggesting.  I will have to do some research on what you are suggesting and come back to you, that might take a few days.

Comment: Thanks @RamRaider I can not figure this out, I am going to work from a visible form with an explanation on the screen for the moment to get it up an running, and devote time to a more elegant solution later. Thanks agian

Comment: Could you use a hidden form element rather than the textarea? Alternatively, for collecting form data prior to POSTing to the server could you use the javascript FormData Object which is intended for precisely this sort of thing? ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData )